# What is the solution to complex Python parameter passing requirement?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I am looking for a solution to the following complex parameter pass problem:

I want to pass function's list along with its parameters as a parameter in another function using Python. I know it is possible to pass function as a parameter,
but is it possible to pass lists of function and its arguments in a python?

My sample code:

```
self.myObject = Column(self.orderedColumnDictionary, \ 
   fillingOutMethods = [[firstFillingOutMethod, parameter1], \
   [anotherFillOutMethod, parameter2, parameter3]])
```

In this code, I am initializing  an object of a class Column. So here while creating an object, I want to pass various functions as parameter. And I am thinking to pass all the functions that is needed for this object as a lits. For example, here in this sample code, my functions are firstFillingOutMethod, where I pass parameter1 as a parameter and my another function is 
anotherFillOutMethod, where I want to pass parameter2 and parameter3 as arguments.

Therefore I am looking forward for any suggestion to perform this kind of task.

Thank you

Comment: Yep you can do it like this, you just need to process the list properly in your function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
def f1(a):
    return a*a

def f2(a,b):
    return a*b

flist = [[f1, 2], [f2, 3, 4]]

print [item[0](*item[1:]) for item in flist]
```

the output is:

```
[4, 12]
```

Comment: Thankyou for the solution, but is there is any other way that i can solve the same problem but rather than passing them in a list. In my post, I mention i want to pass as list as I do not know if there could be any other way to do. Thank you.

Comment: I think pass as list is the right choice, or you can pass it as tuples: [(f1, (2,)), (f2, (3,4))], and the calling is changed to item[0](*item[1])